# Cannot debug pod Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have setup the Kubernetes cluster in my cloud. When it setup complete I install kong-ingress-controller in my master node. I'm using:

```
kubectl apply -f https://bit.ly/ kong-ingress
```

Now my container status is still init. I want debug init container. So I used:

```
 kubectl get pods -o=name --all-namespaces | grep kong
```

Response:

```
pod/ingress-kong-6b6b4c4f5-lg6tp
pod/kong-migrations-grvph
```

Next I using command:

```
kubectl logs pod/ingress-kong-6b6b4c4f5-lg6tp -c init-container-name
```

But I get:

```
Error from server (NotFound): pods "ingress-kong-6b6b4c4f5-lg6tp" not found
```

I dont know why I get this error. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the raw file on [that URL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/master/deploy/single/all-in-one-postgres.yaml) you will notice that the deployments and as a result pods are in namespace kong

```
  namespace: kong
```

The namespaces are used to logically isolate resources within a cluster and you can read [more here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/)

Now for your log command to work, you will have to add a namespace flag like this:

```
kubectl logs -n kong pod/ingress-kong-6b6b4c4f5-lg6tp -c init-container-name
```

Notice the `-n kong` in the logs command, and hopefully it should work